# Print list in specified range Python

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python and I have this problem

I have a list of numbers like this:

```
n = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
```

I want to print from 11 to 37, that means the output = 11, 13,.... 37.

I tried to `print(n[11:37])` but of course it will print [37, 41, 43, 47] 
because that is range index.

Any ideas or does Python have any built-in method for this ?

Comment: `print([i for i in n if i in range(11, 38)])` or something like that

Comment: If the list is sorted as in your example, you can use the builtin `bisect` module for a more efficient index lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job...

```
n = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
n.sort()

mylist = [x for x in n if x in range(11, 38)]
print(mylist)
```

Want to print that as comma separated string:

```
print(mylist.strip('[]'))
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work. (Assuming list is sorted)

```
print n[n.index(11): n.index(37)+1]
```

Output:

```
[11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37]
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your list is ordered and it has no duplicates:

```
n = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]

print(",".join(map(str,n[n.index(11): n.index(37)+1])))
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/NaturalEmotionalError)

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
narr = np.array(n)
m = (narr >= 11) & (narr <= 37)
for v in narr[m]:
    print(v)
# or, to get rid of the loop:
print('\n'.join(map(str, narr[m])))
```

Answer (score 0):

it pretty simple, since your list is already sorted you can write

```
 my_list = [x for x in n if x in range(11, 38)]
 print(*my_list)
```

what the '*' does is that it unpacks the array into individual elements, a term known as unpacking.This will produce the actual result you wanted and not an array

Answer (score -2):

If your data is sorted, you can use a generator expression with either a `range` object or chained comparisons:

```
n = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]

print(*(i for i in n if i in range(11, 38)), sep=', ')   
print(*(i for i in n if 11 <= i <= 37), sep=', ')
```

If your data is unsorted and you can use indices of the first occurrences of each value, you can slice your list:

```
print(*n[n.index(11): n.index(37)+1], sep=', ')
```

Result with the data you have provided:

```
11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37
```